# ESP8266 occasionally stops receiving data

Tags: esp8266

So I have an ESP8266 board that I am using to control some LED lights. I wasn't a fan of the needing to reflash my board everytime I wanted to try a new light pattern, so I decided to send the light data over wifi (UDP), and that works for certain light patterns, but any pattern that has leds that turn on/off starts to stutter and stop after a while. If every light is on, there's no problem with the speed I'm sending data, but if there are some that are on and some off, without fail it will always stop receiving data at a certain point. I've got a couple points of failure and this is my first time messing with an arduino so I'm not sure whether the problem could be on my local program, on the program for the board, the data, my wifi, or something else.

Comment: You should probably describe how the board and leds are powered and how many leds.  In short, it sounds ultimately like a power problem this is being revealed when you request a change.

Comment: do you have a question?  ... you described the problem, but there is nothing that can be answered

Comment: does it stop until reboot, or does it just pause? You might want to try dumping `system_get_free_heap_size()` to see if you have a mem leak.

Comment: It was a memory leak! The data I was sending was slowly growing due to some poor math on my end; fixed that up and it worked great.

Answer (score 1):

dandavis helped me find the answer! Turns out it was a memory leak, due to some poor math on my end. All I had to do was fix that up and it worked fine.